# Can we use the notation of an array for a memory allocated by malloc?

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

I found this piece of code, and I don't understand what it means. Do we have the right to use the array notation like here?

```
double *myList = malloc(3 * sizeof(double));
myList[0] = 1.2;
myList[1] = 2.3;
myList[2] = 3.4;
```

EDIT : I think this notation uses the fact that the memory address of myList[0],myList[1],myList[2]  are consecutive. malloc() doesn't guarantee that the addresses are allocated consecutively.

Comment: yes, this is how you dynamically allocate an array

Comment: Yes. `myList[x]` is really using pointer arithmetic to get to element `x` and then a dereference of that location. That is, `myList[x]` is equivalent to `*(myList + x)`

Comment: Suggest reading a book on C.

Comment: I read 2 books actually but for beginners . they don't go to deep .

Comment: `x[y]` is always equivalent to `*(x+y)`, no matter what x and y are

Comment: Your edit makes no sense; `malloc` makes a block of 3 contiguous `double`s here.

Comment: @Matt NcNabb : Thanks, the situation is more clear for me now .

Comment: Elements allocated in a *single* `malloc`/`calloc`/`realloc` call will be contiguous.  Elements allocated across multiple calls are not guaranteed to be contiguous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
double *myList = malloc(3 * sizeof(double));
```

It is allocating memory for 3 `double` typed data in pointer myList. Following lines assigning `double` typed data on those locations.

```
myList[0] = 1.2;
myList[1] = 2.3;
myList[2] = 3.4;
```

`myList[2]` is equivalent `*(myList+2)`.

You need to deallocate this memory using `free` as follows after its usage:

```
free(myList);
```

`malloc` allocates consecutive locations in memory.

Comment: there's no need to cast. this is C.

Comment: You don't need to cast the return of malloc. In fact, some people [advise against it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). I personally don't think it's a problem either way but since it is debatable it should not be presented as a must do.

Comment: Is there something wrong with `double *myList = malloc(3 * sizeof *mylist);` If you always use the `sizeof object` you are creating, there is never a chance of error in the cast.

Comment: why should I cast the pointer returned by malloc() ? I read by some answers that it's useless in C .

Comment: You shouldn't, `malloc` returns a memory address (which is always `void`), so there is never a need to cast it. @MichaelHeidelberg if you are confused about the prior comment, the cast referred to `sizeof (double)` verses `sizeof *myList`. If you always use **your** object ,there is never a chance of getting the `sizeof (some type)` wrong.  which is what I probably should have said `:p`

Comment: I understand ; but if malloc() returns consecutive memory ; what's the difference between it  ( malloc() ) and calloc() ? ( I know that calloc() initialize the pointer to memory )

Comment: @MichaelHeidelberg You already marked one  of the differences. `malloc()`,`calloc()` and `reaclloc()`  allocates consecutive memory.

Comment: I didn't know it , just one last question , it's always guaranteed  that the memory will be consecutively allocated ? or it's matter of the OS, Hardware ...  ?

Comment: @MichaelHeidelberg It is guaranteed as per my knowledge at least in *NIX systems, where I am familiar.

Comment: One important thing to consider is that `malloc()` returns `NULL` on failure, robust programs must prevent undefined behavior at all cost, and the lack of checking the returned pointer, is potentially Undefined Behavior.

Comment: I cannot find a `man` page that actually states that it is contiguous. But maybe because it is so obvious.

Comment: @MichaelHeidelberg: Consider this: If the allocated memory were *not* contiguous, how would  you find out where it is? `malloc()` and friends always allocate a contiguous block of memory of the requested size.

Comment: @jongware : same probleme for me. I didn't read that it allocates contiguous memory , but for calloc() they state it . question : why for calloc() and not for malloc() ? .

Comment: @Greg Hewgill : I understand . but I think we can develop a way to find where the memory is even if it's not contiguous. it is often possible to do something if it doesn't produce paradoxes. but for a reason of simplicity I think, malloc() allocates contiguous memory I think .

Comment: @MichaelHeidelberg: it's stated explicitly in `calloc` because one may otherwise think it behaves *different* from `malloc`, and on a call such as `calloc(3,5)` (with `count` as 3 and `size` as 5) it *could* return "three blocks of 5 bytes each" (which it does – **but** also contiguously).